# Can not access admin console of jboss eap 6 at standalone mode

Tags: amazon-ec2, jboss7.x, jboss-eap-6

I've installed Jboss eap 6.1 in a micro instance of amazon ec2 server. I've run the standalone.sh and that seems to be running fine:

```
[ec2-user@ip-******** bin]$ ./standalone.sh 
=========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /home/ec2-user/jboss-eap-6.1

  JAVA: /usr/lib/jvm/java/bin/java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Xms64m -Xmx86m -XX:MaxPermSize=64m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true

=========================================================================

20:58:47,062 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.2.0.Final-redhat-1
20:58:47,506 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.0.4.GA-redhat-1
20:58:47,745 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015899: JBoss EAP 6.1.0.GA (AS 7.2.0.Final-redhat-8) starting
20:58:50,396 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-2) XNIO Version 3.0.7.GA-redhat-1
20:58:50,426 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-2) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.7.GA-redhat-1
.......
20:58:52,215 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBWS022052: Starting JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.1.3.Final-redhat-3
20:58:53,245 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBWEB003001: Coyote HTTP/1.1 initializing on : 127.0.0.1:8080
20:58:53,272 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBWEB003000: Coyote HTTP/1.1 starting on: 127.0.0.1:8080
20:58:54,125 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017100: Listening on 127.0.0.1:9999
20:58:54,174 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /home/ec2-user/jboss-eap-6.1/standalone/deployments
20:58:54,174 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
20:58:54,180 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017100: Listening on 127.0.0.1:4447
20:58:54,510 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on 127.0.0.1:9990/management
20:58:54,512 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on 127.0.0.1:9990
20:58:54,512 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: JBoss EAP 6.1.0.GA (AS 7.2.0.Final-redhat-8) started in 8410ms - Started 123 of 177 services (53 services are passive or on-demand)
```

However, when I tried to access the admin console at: myhostname:8080 it gives a "could not connect" error.

I am sure the port 8080 and 9990 are both open as I've installed jboss-as 7.1 and was able to access the admin console of that through myhostname:8080... Then I stop the service of jboss-as 7.1 and started jboss-eap-6.1 and tried to access it...

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like the management console is only listening on 127.0.0.1.

```
20:58:54,512 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on 127.0.0.1:9990
```

You can change it by editing the standalone.xml or using the `-bmanagement 0.0.0.0` parameter. You can replace `0.0.0.0` with the public IP.

Comment: Awesome James! Just saved my day! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Just thought I'd mention that a far safer way to connect is via an SSH Tunnel.

### linux/mac:

1) `ssh -N i [PEM FILE PATH] -L 9992:127.0.0.1:9990 [EC2 username]@[EC2address]`

2) then connect via browser to `http://localhost:9992/console/`

### Windows (Putty):

Follow the steps in the link below (exactly as you did to setup SSH to your EC2 which you should already have). But this time, you need to add the tunnel as per these instructions:

Connection -> SSH -> Tunnels - Enter:

1. Source port: `9992`
2. Destination: `localhost:9990`
   Then conncect via the SSH connection

then connect via browser to `http://localhost:9992/console/`

**Here are further details on setting up a standard SSH connection to EC2**

Connect via SSH to EC2 using Linux/MAC guide here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html

Connect via SSH to EC2 using Windows (Putty) guide here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html